# How do we interpret the images of weights in logistic regression

Tags: weights, logistic-regression

The following images are

a) The weights of a logistic regression model trained on MNIST.

b) The sign of the weights of a logistic regression

How do these images  represent the weights?

Would be grateful for any help.

[Source of the research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6572)

[image]

Comment: It depends on what you are training the model for. If you are trying to classify a face weights will be given to things like eyes nose etc. Just think how would you recognise something, and thats how the LR model will distribute the weights, how the features affect the classification (this is an overgenralization, but you get the idea)

Comment: I understand, maybe you can write it as an answer

Comment: Sorry it takes a long time to write an answer, and I am very short of time. But this actually a very common concept. You can find this in any introductory NN book. This is basically what we call Hebbian Learning. The very first paradigm of computational learning.

Comment: Thank you very much!